How to install driver for Broadcom WiFi card on iMac24 running Ubuntu 24.04?
All,
I have searched and searched (even the Broadcom site) but can find no reference to the WiFi chip in my iMac.
It is listed as BRCM4378 a Broadcom 4378 (0x14E4,0x4378) but I cannot find any reference to a 4378 chip even on the Broadcom site.
How do I find out which drivers I should use?
Geoff

First, connect to internet using USB tethering from your phone.
Next, open Software and Sources, and open the Additional Software tab.
It should list a driver for your WiFi card. Install it, and reboot.
Afterward, WiFi should work.
